# Unable to configuration-tool.sh from putty

Tags: linux, ibm-mobilefirst

I ran  /opt/IBM/Worklight/shortcuts/configuration-tool.sh

I got the below error in logs.

```
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:914)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:900)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ui.Application.start(Application.java:31)
 at         org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Please help in fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Worklight Server Configuration Tool is, as documented [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html), a graphical tool, that is, a program with a graphical user interface. It is not possible to run such programs through terminal emulators such as PuTTY without X option, 'ssh' without X option, 'screen', or similar.

You have two options:

- Use the Worklight Server Configuration Tool through a network connection that supports a graphical user interface. Examples of such network protocols are VNC, PuTTY with X option, ssh with X option, RDP, or ssh/telnet with 'export DISPLAY' (the latter being deprecated for security reasons). For PuTTY with X option, you find some configuration recipes through a web search for "putty x11", and even a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRsma2vkEQE).
- Use the [samples based approach](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_ant_tasks_sample_config_files.html) for setting up a Worklight Server, without using the Worklight Server Configuration Tool. This path can be a bit more tedious, but you only need a text-mode connection to complete it.